# how to create trigger on table after insert to add Row in Audit table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i want to Create a trigger on student table after insert to add Row in Student Audit table (Server User Name , Date, Note) where note will be “[username] Insert New Row with Key=[Key Value] in table student

```
create trigger t1 on Student
after insert
as
declare @x int
begin
insert into Audit
(ServerUserName, Date, Note)
select SUSER_SNAME(), getdate(),SUSER_SNAME()+'Insert New Row with Key'+@x+'in Student '
from Student t
end
go
```

how can i do this with @x that's i mean @x is equal key

Comment: Would you clarify please, what is exactly @x ? It is unique id of inserted row  ?

Comment: i want to insert into note cell that servername in date(y) insert new row with key (x) .. x is id in student table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, remove `declare @x int` line. You can't pass parameters to trigger. If you want to get inserted row, you can select it as `inserted` like this;

```
create trigger t1 on Student
after insert
as
begin
    insert into Audit
    (ServerUserName, Date, Note)
    select SUSER_SNAME(), getdate(),SUSER_SNAME()+'Insert New Row with Key'+cast(t.Id as nvarchar(10))+'in Student '
    from Student t where Id IN (select Id from inserted)
end
go
```